# Getting user-information from multiple twitter users in a single request?

Tags: twitter

I have stored the login information from twitter users (e.g. access-
tokens) in my database.
I now want to get the retweet-count of all these users in a single
request.

Otherwise I have to send 1000 requests if I have 1000 users in my
database (which would lead to blacklisting I guess...).

Is there a comon way to get information from multiple users without
sending requests for each user?

BTW: I'm using Google App Engine and twitter4j

Thanks so far

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `retweet-count`? Users do not have such a count. Only statuses do. Are you trying to find the number of times a users has had one of their statuses retweeted? Or the number of times a user has retweeted someone else's status? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous about the retweet count. What I want to do is to get the total count of how often users statuses got retweeted. For example, if a user has 100 tweets, and each one of them got retweeted 5 times, the total retweed count would be 500. To achieve this, I could crawl through all the users statuses, get the retweet-count and sum it up. On a highly active users, this could violate against the REST-request-limits. AND in a next step, I want do this for a list of users... which would violate the request-limit pretty quick.

Comment: I updated my answer with info about getting retweet_counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API method you are looking for is [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup). It will allow you to get up to 100 user objects in a single request.

To get a count of the number of times a user has had a status of theirs retweeted your bets bet is to use [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline). You can include a `count` of `200` parameter that will return up to 200 statues in a single method. Each status object contains a `retweet_count` value that is generally pretty accurate. You will have to add all of those numbers together.

Comment: Right, but in this particular case there is no attribute for fetching the retweet count. I guess there is no good way for requesting the total amount of retweets from a couple of users in just a few requests. Thanks anyway